# How do I rotate daily backups using rsync?

Tags: bash, cron, backup, rsync

I want to take daily snapshots of a directory which is itself an offsite backup (of a Google Drive account). I want something simple to review and restore, so that excludes `rdiff-backup` or something similar. I don't mind keeping a number of duplicated snapshots of the directory, but don't want something difficult to maintain.

Comment: This is a top hit on Google for this type of backup retention which is my primary requirement. However, I'm looking for something with a GUI, unless I'm forced to use a script so I created a post in SE-software-reqs here: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/84066/linux-ubuntu-backup-with-incremental-and-smart-retention

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[rsnapshot](http://rsnapshot.org/) does exactly this. You can find all the documentation you need on their site.

Comment: It's a little confusing, but I think it's a better outcome than my solution.

Answer (score 4):

I came up with this solution. It will keep 7 full daily snapshots of the backup directory, under the week day name. After 7 days it will overwrite the oldest day.

**crontab**

```
@hourly rsync -a /data/ /snapshots/data/`date +%w-%A`
@daily rsync -a --delete /data/ /snapshots/data/`date +%w-%A`
```

**result**

```
$ du -sh /snapshots/data/*
36G 2-Tuesday
36G 3-Wednesday
...
```